# Form always invalid when running in pytest

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, pytest-django

I'm having an issue trying to get valid form in pytest. I am testing data changes through a Django Admin action. No matter what data I post to the form, `form.is_valid()` will always return `False`. Passing a dictionary to the form directly works, however I would like to be able to test through the action to make sure that the action filters out the locked records.

```py
# test_admin.py

@pytest.mark.django_db
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    """Base TestCase with utilites to create user and login client."""

    def setUp(self):
        """Class setup."""
        self.index_url = '/'
        self.login()
        self.django_db_setup()

    def create_user(self):
        """Create user and returns username, password tuple."""
        username, password = 'testadmin', 'password123'
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(
            username,
            'admin@test.com',
            password,
            first_name='Admin',
            last_name='Account',
        )
        self.user = user
        return (username, password)

    def login(self):
        """Log in client session."""
        username, password = self.create_user()
        self.client.login(username=username, password=password)

    @staticmethod
    def django_db_setup():
        call_command('loaddata', 'fixtures/fixture.json')


class AdminTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    def test_responsible_list(self):
        products = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=[230005, 229724])
        form_data = {
            'action': 'set_product_class',
            'apply': 'Submit',
            'product_class': '1',
            ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME: products.values_list('pk', flat=True),
        }
        self.client.post('/admin/store/product/', form_data, follow=True)
        # Assert product_classes have changed


# actions.py

def set_product_class(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    # Exclude products that are locked
    queryset = queryset.exclude(is_locked=True)
    form = None
    if 'apply' in request.POST:
        form = SetProductClassForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           # action code


# forms.py

class SetProductClassForm(forms.Form):
    _selected_action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput)
    product_class = forms.ModelChoiceField(ProductClass.objects.all())
```

I put a pdb trace above the line in the action where it checks `if form.is_valid():`

When I run this in pytest:

```py
(Pdb) form.is_valid()
False
(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'action': [u'set_product_class'], u'apply': [u'Submit'], u'product_class': [u'1'], u'_selected_action': [u'230005', u'229724']}>
```

However if I run the same code through the Django shell, the form is valid:

```py
(Pdb) form.is_valid()
True
(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'action': [u'set_product_class'], u'apply': [u'Submit'], u'product_class': [u'1'], u'_selected_action': [u'230005', u'229724']}>
```

Why can I not get a valid form through pytest?

Comment: what is form.errors?

Comment: `{'product_class': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}`   I see.. I must be missing the data for the product_class with id of one in the fixture. Thanks!

Comment: Don't assume ids in tests, fetch them from your test db.

Comment: Good advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking `form.errors` gave the following:

```py
{'product_class': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}
```

The issue was being caused by the data for the `ProductClass` being selected in the form was missing in the fixture. Adding the data to the test db fixed the issue.